# Change the content of text file in onclick() method of dialogue box

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Problem is the string which writes to outputstreamswriter has correct value but in try/catch block within onclick() method of dialogue box outputstreamwriter is not working. My file name is default.txt i'm sure file name has nothing to do with the problem. outputstreamwriter does not change the content of file whatsoever i've tried bufferwriter or fileoutputstream but nothing seems to work. Kindly help i'm losing my mind from days now!

here's the code.

```
package zafus.personalitymeter;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.R.integer;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;

public class ChoseAnswers extends Activity {
private final String TAG="";
public String vale;

public List<String> obj;
public int numOfAnswers=0;
//public RelativeLayout mylayout =(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.calayout);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chose_answers);
    obj=null;
    obj=readFromFile("answer.txt", this);
    numOfAnswers=Integer.valueOf(obj.get(0).toString());
    int i=1;
    LinearLayout mylayout =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);

    while(i<=numOfAnswers){
        Button tt = new Button(this);
        tt.setText(obj.get(i));
        tt.setId(i+1);
        tt.setPadding(5, 10, 5, 10);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  
        tt.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                vale=((Button)v).getText().toString();
                AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert1  = new AlertDialog.Builder(ChoseAnswers.this);
                dlgAlert1.setMessage("Show this answer as a result of next test?");

                dlgAlert1.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        obj=null;
                        obj=readFromFile("default.txt", ChoseAnswers.this);
                        obj.set(1,vale);
                        String receiveString = "";
                        int num=Integer.valueOf(obj.get(0))+2;
                        StringBuilder ab = new StringBuilder();
                        int i=0;
                        for(;i<num;i++){
                            ab.append(obj.get(i)+"\n");
                        }

                        receiveString=ab.toString();

                        try {
                            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("default.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
                             //outputStreamWriter.write("");
                            outputStreamWriter.write(receiveString);  
                            outputStreamWriter.close();
                            }


                        catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "File write failed: " + e.toString());
                        }

                        ChoseAnswers.this.finish(); 
                    }});  

                dlgAlert1.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                    }});
            dlgAlert1.show();


            }
        });
        if (i == 1){

            params.setMargins(0, 150, 0, 20);

        }
        else{
            params.setMargins(0, 20, 0, 20);
        }
        tt.setLayoutParams(params);
        tt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bxml);
        tt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#330011"));
        mylayout.addView(tt);


       i++;
    }

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.choseanswers, menu);
    return true;
}


public static List<String> readFromFile(String fileName, Context context) {

List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

InputStream fIn = null;
InputStreamReader isr = null;
BufferedReader input = null;
try {
    fIn = context.getResources().getAssets().open(fileName, context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
    input = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line = "";
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        words.add(line);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.getMessage();
} finally {
    try {
        if (isr != null)
            isr.close();
        if (fIn != null)
            fIn.close();
        if (input != null)
            input.close();
    } catch (Exception e2) {
        e2.getMessage();
    }
}



return words;
```

}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your onClick you read a file from assets and save it to internal memory. 
On the next click the same happens. 
You should read the file from internal memory too if you want to check if the write succeeded.

Comment: Isn't the file in assets are actually the files in internal memory

Comment: I have used getfiledirectory() method too, it didn't work either

Comment: getfiledirectory() ? You did not post that code. And no, assets is quit different from internal memory. The assets directory is determined in Eclipse by the assets folder in your project.

Comment: When apk forms how assets file save in internal memory. and now if i have to read the file from internal memory can you give me some code about that thanks!

Comment: Make a copy of `readFromFile` which you name `readFromAssets`. Then in `readFromFile` you only have to change the line `fIn = context.getResources().getAssets().open(fileName, context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);` to `fIn = context.openFileInput(fileName, context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);`. How to copy a file from assets to internal memery you already know because that's what you did all te time. Well dirty, but anyhow.